# Random whole number between two integers algorithm doesn’t work as expected?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I’m trying to dissect the random number (between two integers) algorithm provided by MDN. I do that by simply plugging in numbers and walking through the algorithm step by step on a piece of scratch paper.

***Expected result***: The random number between a range can go up to, and in fact include the max number.

I’m a bit confused about how to test it, mainly because I feel like I could be doing something wrong given the results.

***Actual results***: No matter what min/max I choose - my test results appear to demonstrate that the algorithm actually cannot ever result in a random number that goes “near” the max number. The result I always get will never go higher than (max-min). I’m not sure if this is the only issue with this algorithm, but it is the most obvious.

```
// Example
function ourRandomRange(ourMin, ourMax) {

  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ourMax - ourMin + 1)) + ourMin;
}

ourRandomRange(5, 15);
```

Comment: what is actually the problem? do you have some number to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: In your second example the `max` and `min` variables have not been defined, so it won't run.

Comment: Based on your first example: `Math.random()` returns a number between `0` and `0.999...` inclusive. Let's say we get the max value, `0.999...`. The formula becomes: `Math.floor(0.999 * 9) + 1`. The first part becomes `8.999` and gets floored to `8`. `8 + 1` is `9`. So in theory, you can get 9

Comment: All you need to do is call the function about a 100 times, and print the result each time. You should see every number about 10 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call the function n times and have a look to the distribution.

You get all wanted numbers equally distributed.

```js
function ourRandomRange(ourMin, ourMax) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ourMax - ourMin + 1)) + ourMin;
}

var count = {},
    value;

for (var i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    value = ourRandomRange(5, 15)
    count[value] = (count[value] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is what I needed.  It demonstrates that my methods were flawed and that the number can actually be much closer to the "max" than I had initially believed.